# Computer running Windows 7 with a Ouragan Neo900 UPS

Tags: ups

We have a number of power issues here on Mauritius and I wondered if there is any software that, when the UPS kicks in during a power loss, can then safely shut down my computer as although I purchased a UPS has proved useless when the power loss is longer than the UPS battery, the computer just shuts off.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you go for a manageable UPS like Cyberpower UPS with [cyberpower power panel](http://www.howtogeek.com/183102/how-to-gracefully-shutdown-your-pc-with-a-ups-unit-and-why-you-should/) or APC back ups with [powerchute](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33776/powerchute-makes-managing-your-apc-ups-easier-during-power-outages/)